# XPath: Find element that contains text X and not Y

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm attempting to find a web element using XPath in `Selenium` for Python. The web element should contain the text *"Chocolate"* but not include *"Dark"*.

I've tried this syntax but not gotten it to work (be mindful of parantheses):

```
choco = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(., 'Chocolate')] and not[[contains(., 'Dark')]]]")
```

Here is the same code using line breaks and concatenation for readability:

```
choco = driver.find_element_by_xpath((
                                    "//*[text()[contains(., 'Chocolate')]" + 
                                    "and not[[contains(., 'Dark')]]]"
                                    ))
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? The syntax of your XPath query looks wrong, try `.../text()[contains(... ) and not contains(... )]`

Comment: @Markus: `"//*[text()[contains(., 'Chocolate') and not contains(., 'Dark')]]"` SyntaxError: Not a legal expression.

Comment: Dang, I'm not in front of my computer right now, so I can't work out the exact syntax... But I think I missed two parentheses: `... and not(... )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try following `XPath` and let me know if any errors occurs:

```
//*[contains(text(), "Chocolate")][not(contains(text(), "Dark"))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax with using just one set of square brackets.

For elements containing the word 'Chocolate' but not 'Dark', use:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Chocolate') and not(contains(text(), 'Dark'))]
```

For just the text of the elements, use:

```
//text()[contains(., 'Chocolate') and not(contains(., 'Dark'))]
```

Given the following XML:

```
<doc>
  <e>Dark Chocolate</e>
  <e>Chocolate</e>
</doc>
```

The first expression results in:

```
> xpath -e "//*[contains(text(), 'Chocolate') and not(contains(text(), 'Dark'))]" test.xml 
<e>Chocolate</e>
```

The second expression results in:

```
> xpath -e "//text()[contains(., 'Chocolate') and not(contains(., 'Dark'))]" test.xml 
Chocolate
```